# What does <%- body %> represent in EJS with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, view, ejs

From here: https://github.com/tj/ejs#features

`Unescaped buffering with <%- body %>`

This is my `layout.ejs`:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <%- body %>
    </div>

    <!-- Dismissible alerts/popup messages from Bootstrap.com -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

It was mentioned in the tutorial that

```
<div class="container">
  <%- body %>
</div>
```

is used to render the views.

Please explain what does the word `'body'` do there and how does this work?

Comment: In this case `body` is just a variable, it could have been declared in the same page, or passed from node

Comment: @DivineSoul I will get back on this soon. Thank you.